# OSMDROID OnItemGestureListener

Tags: java, android, dictionary, osmdroid

i need help on my codes concerning the osmdroid feature,
when i tap the marker it does not return the title and description

can anyone help me... this is my

CODE

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
 import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedIconOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.OverlayItem;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ScaleBarOverlay;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidOpenStreetMapViewActivity extends Activity {

private MapView myOpenMapView;
private MapController myMapController;

ArrayList<OverlayItem> anotherOverlayItemArray;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myOpenMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.openmapview);
    myOpenMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myMapController = myOpenMapView.getController();
    myMapController.setZoom(2);

    //--- Create Another Overlay for multi marker
    anotherOverlayItemArray = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
      "0, 0", "0, 0", new GeoPoint(0, 0)));
    anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
      "US", "US", new GeoPoint(38.883333, -77.016667)));
    anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
      "China", "China", new GeoPoint(39.916667, 116.383333)));
    anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
      "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", new GeoPoint(51.5, -0.116667)));
    anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
      "Germany", "Germany", new GeoPoint(52.516667, 13.383333)));
    anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
      "Korea", "Korea", new GeoPoint(38.316667, 127.233333)));
    anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
      "India", "India", new GeoPoint(28.613333, 77.208333)));
    anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
      "Russia", "Russia", new GeoPoint(55.75, 37.616667)));
    anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
      "France", "France", new GeoPoint(48.856667, 2.350833)));
    anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
      "Canada", "Canada", new GeoPoint(45.4, -75.666667)));

    ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> anotherItemizedIconOverlay 
     = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(
       this, anotherOverlayItemArray, myOnItemGestureListener);
    myOpenMapView.getOverlays().add(anotherItemizedIconOverlay);
    //---

    //Add Scale Bar
    ScaleBarOverlay myScaleBarOverlay = new ScaleBarOverlay(this);
    myOpenMapView.getOverlays().add(myScaleBarOverlay);
}

OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem> myOnItemGestureListener
= new OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>(){

 @Override
  public boolean onItemLongPress(int arg0, OverlayItem arg1) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return false;
  }

 @Override
  public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(int index, OverlayItem item) {
  Toast.makeText(AndroidOpenStreetMapViewActivity.this, 
 item.mDescription + "\n"
 + item.mTitle + "\n"
 + item.mGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6() + " : " + item.mGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), 
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 return true;
}

};

}
```

thanks... and can anyone suggest a way to display the title and description?..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the ItemizedIconOverlay, use:

- either osmdroid ItemizedOverlayWithFocus
- or [OSMBonusPack Marker](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_0)